# How to fix JS error The file was redirected through an insecure connection.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that generates an URL that is using http:// :( How to modify it to use https://?

```
$("#download-p-xls").click(function(){
        window.location = '{$page_url}{if $search_values}&{else}?{/if}action=p_save';
    });
```

Getting console error:

Mixed Content: The site at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://www.example.com/page1?action=p_save' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

Comment: So page1 is on the same domain like the page it is called from?

Comment: yes the same domain

Comment: and the page1 script is doing what?